# Typo in end date of a contract

Tags: contract-law

I am working with a contract company in the UK (I am in the US) and we need to terminate our contract with them. We have provided written notice on Feb 2, 2023 stating we would like to end service on April 3. They have replied stating that we are in contract with them until July of 2023. Below is the clause stating dates both parties agreed to:

This SOW shall commence on 1 October 2022 ("Effective Date") and continue with no provision for
termination (other than the provisions listed agreed in Clause "Termination" below) until 30 June
2022 ("Initial Term").

Unless terminated by 30 April 2022, the SOW shall tacitly renew from 1 July 2022 onwards from full
calendar quarter to calendar quarter until terminated by either party with a notice period of two
months.

The termination clause states we can exit at any time if the company is liquidated (which is not the case).

Are we bound to stay in the contract until July 2023 even though the contrat states July 2022?

Comment: You're ok with not being paid, right?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim why would they not get paid, when there is a contract in force?

Comment: It ended in 2022.

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim it did not. The contract continues indefinitely until 2 months notice is given before the end of a 3-month calendar quarter.

Answer (score 6):

If the contract commenced on 1st October 2022 the dates 30 April 2022 and 1 July 2022 are plainly a mistake (2022 for 2023). If so, you can give notice before 30th April 2023 to terminate at the end of June.

Even if you want to hold them to those dates, the current "full calendar quarter" (which has been tacitly renewing) will end on 31st March, and 2nd February was too late to give the required 2 months notice.

Either way, the contract cannot end until 30th June 2023, the end of the next full calender quarter.

Comment: Agreed. If the error was 30 June 2023 and it was meant to be 30 June 2024, correcting the clerical error might be more challenging, but when the clerical error leads to a clear and obvious contradiction it can be deemed reformed to the intent of the parties without a court proceeding to reform it as a general rule.